# Advice on repairing the errors in this C++ void function for a homework problem

Tags: c++, debugging

I am a college student looking for help on picking up the messy bits in this code I've worked on for class. I believe there's an error in this code that CodeBlocks is finicky with.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
void func1();
void func2();
int main()
{
    int num1, num2;
    double num3;
    int choice;
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    do
    {
        func1();
        cin >> choice;
        cout << endl;
        if (choice == 1)
        {
           func2(num1, num2, num3);
           cout << num1 << ", " << num2 << ", " << num3 << endl;
        }
    }
    while (choice != 99);
    return 0;
 }
void func1()
{
    cout << "To run the program, enter 1." << endl;
    cout << "To exit the program, enter 99." << endl;
    cout << "Enter 1 or 99: ";
}
void func2(int num1, int num2, double num3)
{

    cout << "input 2 bumners a and b";
    cin >> num1;
    cin >> num2;

    if (num1 >= num2){
      num3 = pow(num1, num2);
    }
    else if (num1 < num2){
      num3 = pow(num2, num1);
    }
    else if (num1 != 0 && num2 == 0){
      num3 = sqrt(abs(num1));
    }
    else if (num2 != 0 && num1 == 0){
      num3 = sqrt(abs(num2));
    }
    else if (num1 == 0 && num2 == 0){
      num3 = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking to help identify your problem, or actually using a debugger?

Comment: I need help identifying the problem, and I need help addressing the issue.

Comment: So what's the problem?  Why do you think your code isn't working?  Please [edit] your question to include that information.

Comment: Gotcha, my dude :)

Comment: I ran your code, and the only error I got was that you have a different headers for ```func2()```. To fix this, make sure to include the correct parameters at the top of the code where you declare ```void func2()```.

Comment: you need to post what the program is supposed to do. What do you expect to observe and what you actually observe when compiling/running the program.

Answer (score 1):

Your `func2()` accepts parameters by value; whatever you do to those parameters is not visible outside of that function (when it returns). You should pass by reference.

```
void func2(int& num1, int& num2, double& num3)
```

Comment: Thanks! You really helped me with my grade!

Answer (score 0):

This code isn't too hard to debug. I just tried compiling it, and I was told the error existed at line 6. Here's what you have to do:

Make sure you put in the correct parameters when you declare `void func2()` at line 6. It should have these parameters: `(int num1, int num2, double num3)`.

The parameters must be the same when you declare the function and when you define the function, otherwise the defined function is never declared.

Comment: And I would like to thank you as well.